# NetInfo must be passed to networkMonitor to enable reachability in React Native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

Getting below error for any snapshot testing where the component is using following import

```js
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
```

Test suite failed to run

```
NetInfo must be passed to networkMonitor to enable reachability in React Native

  at ReachabilityNavigator.Object.<anonymous>.ReachabilityNavigator.networkMonitor (node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/src/Util/Reachability.native.ts:20:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-amplify/datastore/src/sync/datastoreReachability/index.native.ts:4:55)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-amplify/datastore/src/sync/datastoreConnectivity.ts:3:1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the `aws-aplify` code, that error is thrown in this [networkMonitor](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/df95ea3724eb6406f64b03f25086cd3e8644cb5f/packages/core/src/Util/Reachability.native.ts#L19) function, which is called in this other [place](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/df95ea3724eb6406f64b03f25086cd3e8644cb5f/packages/datastore/src/sync/datastoreReachability/index.native.ts) where `@react-native-community/netinfo` is used. Mocking the dependency as indicated in the lib [README](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo#errors-while-running-jest-tests) should fix the issue.

> If you do not have a Jest Setup file configured, you should add the
> following to your Jest settings and create the jest.setup.js file in
> project root:
>
> ```
> setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js']
> ```
>
> You should then add the
> following to your Jest setup file to mock the NetInfo Native Module:
>
> ```
> import mockRNCNetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo/jest/netinfo-mock.js';
>
> jest.mock('@react-native-community/netinfo', () => mockRNCNetInfo);
> ```